# sql update using joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
checks 
- payment_id
- send_time

payments
  - id 
  - time
```

each check has a payment id (payments.id). I want to update the payment objects for each check with the check's send time

for example, if check 1 has a send_time of A and a payment ID 3, I want to update payment object ID 3 with time = A

How do I do that using one sql query? update query with joins?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, this should work:

```
update payments p 
    join checks c on p.id = c.payment_id
set p.time = c.send_time
```